# How to draw bar chart with symbolic x axis values and vertical lines separating the group?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a y bar chart with symbolic values for the x axis. I want vertical lines drawn the separate the groups. There are examples of this when the x axis is numeric, but not symbolic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
minor x tick num=1,
xminorgrids,
minor tick length=0,
```

and optionally

```
grid style={<style options for grid lines>}
```

if you want to change the style of those lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    minor x tick num=1,
    xminorgrids,
    minor tick length=0,
    %grid style={densely dashed}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```